# How to load CRL path in openssl 1.0.1?

Tags: openssl

since I've updated to openssl 1.0.1 the revocation check functionality in my application is broken. By the help of "apps/verfiy.c" I've found out that the loading of CRL files has changed, which I've done following until now:

```
X509_LOOKUP *lookup;
const char *crl_path = "/path/to/crls"

X509_VERIFY_PARAM *param = X509_VERIFY_PARAM_new();
X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flags(param, X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK);
SSL_CTX_set1_param(ctx, param);

lookup = X509_STORE_add_lookup(ctx->cert_store, X509_LOOKUP_hash_dir());
if (lookup == NULL) {
  return "CRL path initialization error: X509 lookup initialization failed.";
}
if(!X509_LOOKUP_add_dir(lookup, crl_path, X509_FILETYPE_PEM)) {
  return "CRL path initialization error: path addition failed.";
}

X509_VERIFY_PARAM_free(param);
```

Doing so now I always get the error "unable to load certificate CRL".

However, in "apps/verify.c" CRL files are recently loaded one at a time by following code:

```
STACK_OF(X509_CRL) *crls;
char *crlfile = "/path/to/single/crl"

crls = load_crls(bio_err, crlfile, FORMAT_PEM, NULL, e, "other CRLs");
X509_STORE_CTX_set0_crls(csc, crls);
```

Does anyone know how CRL files can still be loaded by use of lookup routines (e.g., X509_LOOKUP_add_dir) and all at once by the specification of a CRL path?

Answer (score 2):

I know some ways to add the CRL file with the store
Method 1 :
      use this API form x509_vfy.h file .
      `int X509_load_crl_file(X509_LOOKUP *ctx, const char *file, int type);`
here type can be any one of the following value

X509_FILETYPE_PEM           -- for the PEM/B64 encoded CRL file

X509_FILETYPE_ASN1          -- for the DER encoded CRL files

Method 2.

step 1 .convert the  file Into X509_CRL format 
       (To convert use the any one of the below API from the `X509.h` file:

```
      //If the CRL file is DER encoded 
         X509_CRL *d2i_X509_CRL_fp(FILE *fp,X509_CRL **crl);  
      //If the CRL file is PEM encoded 
        PEM_read_X509_CRL_fp();

    )
```

step 2 : create a Stack of CRL's

STACK_OF(X509_CRL) mCRLStack;

step 3 :

```
     X509_STORE_CTX_set0_crls(lStoreCtx,mCRLStack); 
     /* or */
     lStoreCtx->crls = mCRLStack;
```

Comment: I've found the reason why the check did not work anymore. I guess the hash function within openssl changed and so the files could not be found by means of the expected hash-links.

I have renewed the links to the CRL files and now everything works as expected.

For example:
    `ln -s <CRL_FILE> $(openssl crl -hash -noout -in <CRL_FILE>).r0`

Thanks anyway!!!!